# Oprtical Flow artifacts on cuts in Premiere

Tags: premiere, adobe

I rendered a video using Optical Flow (it includes lots of Time Remapping). Basic cuts look as if there was a short glitch-like transition between them.

Frame of first shot
[[image: Frame of first shot][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcK6W.jpg)

Frame between two
[image: Frame between two]

Comment: Welcome! It isn't clear what you are asking. Could you expand your question and perhaps post a sample video instead of just screen shots?

Comment: What it's doing is trying to optical flow between the two scenes. You may have to render out the clips individually with 1 or two frame "handles", and then trim them back down.

Answer (score 2):

Did you apply the Optical Flow to a nested sequence that contains a transition?  This looks to me like Optical Flow trying to invent new frames to fill in the slow motion and getting confused by the fact that a transition is blending two different videos.  You should apply your time remaps to the base clips and then do transitions on top of the already adjusted clips.